# Determining the of grid used by circle

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I would like to determine the proportion of a grid cell occupied by one (or more) circles. So, for example, the top left grid cell below would have a small value (~0.1) and the center grid cell (7,7) would have a value of 1, as it is entirely occupied by the circle.

[image: problem view]

At present I am doing this with canvas.context2d.getImageData, by sampling the cell's content to determine what is present.  This works but is *way* too slow. This is this method:

```
var boxRadius = 6;
var boxSize = boxRadius * 2 + 1;

var cellWidth = gridWidth / boxSize;
var cellHeight = gridHeight / boxSize;  
var scanInterval = 10;
var scanCount = 10;
  for (var x = viewcenterpoint.x - (gridWidth / 2); x <= viewcenterpoint.x + (gridWidth / 2) -1; x += cellWidth) {        
        for (var y = viewcenterpoint.y - (gridHeight / 2) ; y <= viewcenterpoint.y + (gridHeight / 2) -1; y += cellHeight) {
            var cellthreatlevel = 0.0;

            for (var cellx = x; cellx < x + cellWidth; cellx += scanInterval){
                for (var celly = y; celly < y + cellHeight; celly += scanInterval){
                    var pixeldata = context.getImageData(cellx, celly, 1, 1).data;
                    cellthreatlevel += ((pixeldata[0] + pixeldata[1] + pixeldata[2])/765 * -1) + 1;//255; //grey tone
                    scancount += 1;
               }  
            } 

            cellthreatlevel = cellthreatlevel / scanCount; //mean
        }
    }
```

The getImageData call is the source of the problem - it is way too slow.

Given that I have an array of circles, each with their x, y and radius how can I calculate this?  If possible I would like each value to be a decimal fraction (between 0 and 1).

The grid is static, but the circles may move within it.  I would be happy to get a rough estimate for the value, it doesnt need to be 100% accurate.

Comment: The slowness can be attributed to the calls of `getImageData`. It is a little of a pity to perform extra sampling when you have precise data available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Monte Carlo Method** to get an approximate solution. It is a probability based method, in which you generate random samples in order to estimate some value. In this case, given the coordinates of the circle center, the circle radius and the boundaries of the grid cell, you can estimate the proportion of the grid cell occupied by the circle by generating **K** random samples (all contained inside the grid cell), and verify the proportion of the samples that are also inside the circle. The more samples you generate, the more accurate your result will be.

Remember: to verify if a given sample **P** is inside a circle with center **C** and radius **R**, all you have to do is check if the equation **sqrt((Px-Cx)^2 + (Py-Cy)^2) <= R** is true

Answer (score 1):

You only need to call `getImageData` once, to obtain the entire canvas.

Once you have the image data you can access the bytes at offset `4 * (celly * width + cellx)` to get the RGB(A) data.

This should be massively faster since it only makes one call to the graphics hardware instead of 10s of thousands.